# eth-lightwallet installation error

Tags: ethereumjs, meteor, eth-lightwallet, ethereumjs-tx

I'm using Meteor and have installed eth-lightwallet by typing

`meteor npm install --save eth-lightwallet`

and

`meteor npm install --save ethereumjs-tx`

However, when I import lightwallet from "eth-lightwallet" in my client/main.js

the console shows this error message

```
/Users/johnhckuo/.meteor/packages/templating-compiler/.1.3.0.nkq99n++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:177
      throw error;
      ^

TypeError: Cannot set property '/Users/johnhckuo/Desktop/Block-Farm/app/node_modules/ethereumjs-tx/package.json' of undefined
    at Resolver._resolvePkgJsonMain (/tools/isobuild/resolver.js:320:9)
    at Resolver._resolve (/tools/isobuild/resolver.js:123:25)
    at /tools/isobuild/resolver.js:75:19
    at Entry._reallyRecompute (/Users/johnhckuo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_5.bj91mp++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/optimism/lib/entry.js:215:26)
at Entry._recomputeIfDirty (/Users/johnhckuo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_5.bj91mp++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/optimism/lib/entry.js:179:17)
at Entry.recompute (/Users/johnhckuo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_5.bj91mp++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/optimism/lib/entry.js:46:20)
at Resolver.optimistic [as resolve] (/Users/johnhckuo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_5.bj91mp++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/optimism/lib/index.js:50:18)
at ImportScanner._resolve (/tools/isobuild/import-scanner.js:466:36)
```

I've tried using Meteor 1.2, 1.3 and 1.4, but this error keeps popping out

Any suggestions is appreciated guys !